# How to use identify columns of two data frames with same names without giving alias names to them

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

i am getting 2 data frames from the below code.Each data frame has same number of columns and column names

data for f2.csv is

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
k1,i,aa,k
k5,j,ee,l
```

data for f1.csv is

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
k1,a,aa,e
k2,b,bb,f
k3,c,cc,g
k4,d,dd,h
```

i am reading the above two data with following data frames

```
 val avro_inp = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(f1.csv)
 val del_inp = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(f2.csv)
```

i am trying to access individual column with the dataframename.columnname 
it throws the sql exception 
below is the code i am using

```
avro_inp.join(del_inp, Seq("c1", "c3"), "outer")
.withColumn("c2",when(del_inp.col(colName="c2").isNotNull,del_inp.col(colName ="c2")).otherwise(avro_inp.col(colName = "c2")))
.withColumn("c4",when(avro_inp.col(colName="c4").isNull,del_inp.col(colName ="c4")).otherwise(avro_inp.col(colName = "c4")))
.drop(del_inp.col(colName="c2")).drop(del_inp.col(colName="c4")).show()
```

is there any way i can do without adding alias name to the columns.I am getting following error with above code

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'c4' is ambiguous, could be: c4#3, c4#7.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:171)
```

Comment: what is the error? it runs perfectly in mine. and update with sample inputs as well

Comment: i am getting the above exception

Comment: I would suggest you to change the column names of the second table

Comment: you need to update the question again as you reading dataframe name is not matching with joining dataframe name

Comment: i was asked not to change the column names

Comment: it passed in mine. :) what is the spark version? You must be doing something after join, are you?

Comment: i am using spark 1.6 and whats your version of spark

Comment: i am using 2.0. but the drop is not working in mine

Comment: check my answer below. :) hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below where original dataframe names aren't changed. **The following code is tested in spark 2.0**.

```
avro_inp.join(del_inp, Seq("c1", "c3"), "outer")
  .withColumn("c22",when(del_inp.col(colName="c2").isNotNull, del_inp.col(colName ="c2")).otherwise(avro_inp.col(colName = "c2")))
  .withColumn("c44",when(avro_inp.col(colName="c4").isNull,del_inp.col(colName ="c4")).otherwise(avro_inp.col(colName = "c4")))
  .drop("c2", "c4")
  .select($"c1", $"c22".as("c2"), $"c3", $"c44".as("c4"))
```

Comment: @himanshulllTian, why do you need two drops when one is doing fine in mine. :)

Comment: Because in Spark 1.6 `drop` method takes either a `Column` or `String` as input. Not `String*`

Comment: I suspected so :) thats why I accepted :) thanks for the correction @himanshuIIITian

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

**For spark 1.6**.

```
avro_inp.join(del_inp, Seq("c1", "c3"), "outer")
.withColumn("c2_new",when(del_inp.col(colName="c2").isNotNull, del_inp.col(colName ="c2")).otherwise(avro_inp.col(colName = "c2")))
.withColumn("c4_new",when(avro_inp.col(colName="c4").isNull,del_inp.col(colName ="c4")).otherwise(avro_inp.col(colName = "c4")))
.drop(del_inp.col("c4")).drop(avro_inp.col("c4"))
.drop(del_inp.col("c2")).drop(avro_inp.col("c2"))
.select($"c1", $"c2_new".as("c2"), $"c3", $"c4_new".as("c4"))
.show()
```

But if you are using Spark 2.0, then please refer to @RameshMaharjan's answer.

I hope it helps!